# How can I graph in Shiny with the data provided by the user?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `numericImput` to get the data introduced by the user.

I am trying to graph the balistic curve of the proyectil motion described by the input of the user (The user gives a value for intial velocity, angle measure, time of flight and k constant), but I can't solve the mistake :(

Any help would be thanked! :D

Here is my code

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Movimiento de Projectiles"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  width = 2,
  
  numericInput(inputId = "v",
               label = "Velocidad",
               value = " "),
  
  numericInput(inputId = "th",
               label = "Angulo",
               value = " "),
  
  numericInput(inputId = "tf",
               label = "Tiempo",
               value = " "),
  
  numericInput(inputId = "k",
               label = "Constante k",
               value = " ")
  ),

  mainPanel(
  plotOutput("posicion")
    )
   )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {

  v <- renderPrint({ input$v })

  th <- (renderPrint({ input$th}))

  t<-renderPrint({ input$tf })


  k<-renderPrint({ input$k })



  output$posicion <- renderPlot({

  # Para x
  vx<-function(v,th){
  input$v*cos(input$th*((2*pi)/360))
  }

  x<-function(t){
  vx*input$t
  }


  ## Para y
  vy<-function(v,th){
  input$v*sin(input$th*((2*pi)/360))
  }
  y<-function(t){
  (vy*input$t)-(0.5*g*t*t)
  }
  # Dibujamos el grafico de X v.s. Y
  plot(x)
  })
  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you are creating functions, but it is not invoked

Comment: what is `g*t*t` is it `input$t` and not sure about `g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the `ui` and in the `server`

1. In the `numericInput`, the `value` argument would be numeric as well instead of a string (`" "`)
2. Not clear why `renderPrint` was initiated in `server` without having a corresponding `ui` element
3. Functions were created in `server` without invoking it.

Below is a minimal code that gives an output by making couple of changes

- changed the `value = " "` to a numeric initial value
- added `verbatimTextOutput` in `ui` to print the `renderPrint` called in `server
- removed those multiple functions created and simplified with a single expression to `plot`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Movimiento de Projectiles"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      
      numericInput(inputId = "v",
                   label = "Velocidad",
                   value = 22),
      
      numericInput(inputId = "th",
                   label = "Angulo",
                   value = 15),
      
      numericInput(inputId = "tf",
                   label = "Tiempo",
                   value = 41),
      
      numericInput(inputId = "k",
                   label = "Constante k",
                   value = 32)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("posicion"),
      verbatimTextOutput("v"),
      verbatimTextOutput("th"),
      verbatimTextOutput("tf"),
      verbatimTextOutput("k")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$v <- renderPrint({ input$v})
  
  output$th <- (renderPrint({ input$th}))
  
  output$tf<-renderPrint({ input$tf })
  
  
  output$k<-renderPrint({ input$k })
  
  
  
  output$posicion <- renderPlot({
      plot(input$v* cos(input$th*((2*pi)/360)) * input$th)
   
    
   
    
   
 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]